# Phonegap and the latest Framework 7

Tags: javascript, html, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am starting a project in **Phonegap** and selecting the **Framework 7** template option from the template list. This is all well and good but I notice that this template only uses v1.5.0 ... I would like to start my project with the latest v2.0.10.

Can someone please advise me on the best and accepted way to start a fresh Phonegap project using the newest version of Framework 7?
What would be really ace is if someone had a starter template setup for phonegap like the one that comes with phonegap and are willing to share.

Comment: I would download the latest F7 zip and link up the files to my Phonegap project